# PHP: include\require behavior

Tags: php, include, require

whenever we include\require some file using php like

`require ('links.php');` OR `include ('links.php');`

which one of the following two scenarios happen

**EXAMPLE**

lets say there is file `file.php` with the follwing code

```
<?php
echo "my things";
?>
<br />
```

and we include this in

```
------
------
<?php
echo "about to include file";
include ('file.php')
?>
------
------
```

**SCENARIO 1 :**
the included file's code is inserted in the parents\container files PHP Code and then the complete code is processed & HTML\result is generated....

meaning, first this code be first put like

```
------
------
<?php
echo "about to include file";
<?php
echo "my things";
?>
<br />
?>
------
------
```

then processed

**SCENARIO 2 :**
the included file is first processed and the result is plugged in

meaning first the include file will be processed and the result will be obtained

```
mythings<br/>
```

and after that it is placed inside the parent\container\includer code and then that code will be processed neaning

```
------
------
<?php
echo "about to include file";
my things<br />
?>
------
------
```

and now it will be processed

Comment: What is your question exactly? What is the problem?

Comment: p.s SCENARIO 1 can cause syntax errors, SCENARIO 2 can cause Variables problems & a lot other logical & conditional problems

Comment: `@ sarfraz :` there was no problem... just explanation to what is going underneath was desired

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this might not be easiest to understand with just the "include" name...

So - what happens when you do

```
<?php
echo "including now...";
include "myFile.php";
echo "blah";
?>
```

then it will basically turn out like this:

```
<?php
echo "including now...";

?>
CONTENTS OF myFile.php HERE
<?php

echo "blah";
?>
```

Meaning that in your example it would look like this:

```
<?php
echo "about to include file";
?>
<?php
echo "my things";
?>
<br />
<?php
?>
```

Comment: If it were so simple, I wouldn't have needed to post [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941373/processing-include-require-directives-in-php). Any ideas there?

Answer (score 1):

It's scenario one. `include` is a simple mechanism to "inject" code at that line of code.

As a historical tidbit, before PHP 4.1, `include`s used to be processed even if the statement was in a block or condition that was never executed. Other than that, PHP does not have anything that would come close to your scenario 2.

Answer (score 1):

It is scenario one.

Also note that `require` will only put in the code once! so:

```
<?php
echo "about to include file";
require ('file.php');
require ('file.php');
require ('file.php');
echo "included the file";
?>
```

will yield:

```
<?php
echo "about to include file";
?><?php
echo "my things";
?>
<br /><?
echo "included the file";
?>
```

whereas:

```
<?php
echo "about to include file";
include ('file.php');
include ('file.php');
include ('file.php');
echo "included the file";
?>
```

will yield:

```
<?php
echo "about to include file";
?><?php
echo "my things";
?>
<br /><?php
echo "my things";
?>
<br /><?php
echo "my things";
?>
<br /><?php
echo "included the file";
?>
```