# Processing include/require directives in PHP

Tags: php, include

**Background:**
I'm building an automated test framework for a PHP application, and I need a way to efficiently ["stub out"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Double) classes which encapsulate communication with external systems. For example, when testing class X that uses DB wrapper class Y, I would like to be able to "swap in" a "fake" version of class Y while running automated tests on class X (this way I don't have to do full setup + teardown of the state of the real DB as part of the test).

**Problem:**
PHP allows "conditional includes", which means basically that include/require directives are handled as part of processing the "main" logic of a file, e.g.:

```
if (condition) {
    require_once('path/to/file');
}
```

The problem is that I can't figure out what happens when the "main" logic of the included file calls "return". Are all of the objects (defines, classes, functions, etc.) in the included file imported into the file which calls include/require? Or does processing stop with the return?

**Example:**
Consider these three files:

**A.inc**

```
define('MOCK_Z', true);
require_once('Z.inc');
class Z {
    public function foo() {
        print "This is foo() from a local version of class Z.\n";
    }
}
$a = new Z();
$a->foo();
```

**B.inc**

```
define('MOCK_Z', true);
require_once('Z.inc');
$a = new Z();
$a->foo();
```

**Z.inc**

```
if (defined ('MOCK_Z')) {
    return true;
}
class Z {
    function foo() {
        print "This is foo() from the original version of class Z.\n";
    }
}
```

I observe the following behavior:

```
$ php A.inc
> This is foo() from a local version of class Z.

$ php B.inc
> This is foo() from the original version of class Z.
```

**Why This is Strange:**
If require_once() included all of the defined code objects, then "php A.inc" **ought** to complain with a message like

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Z
```

And if require_once() included only the defined code objects up to "return", then "php B.inc" **ought** to complain with a message like:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Z' not found
```

**Question:**
Can anyone explain *exactly* what PHP is doing, here? It actually matters to me because I need a robust idiom for handling includes for "mocked" classes.

Comment: First off, I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Unit testing shouldn't need any hacky defines or conditional includes. But that aside, this is interesting dual behavior. Without the return, you'll get a duplicate class error. Not sure if the manual addresses this or not.

Comment: @Matthew - I was unable to find anything in the PHP manual which explains the behavior which I described in my OP (hence the question). As for unit testing and hacking includes, I have found that in practice it is far from easy to get more than very modest test coverage without injecting mock objects (aka test doubles) somehow, and since PHP doesn't make "monkey patching" very easy (like, say, Python) then I'm forced to choose between hacking includes, physically replacing files, and upend class hierarchies in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've thought about this for a while now, and nobody has been able to point me to a clear and consistent explanation for the way PHP (up to 5.3 anyway) processes includes.

I conclude that it would be better to avoid this issue entirely and achieve control over "test double" class substitution via **[autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)**:

[spl-autoload-register](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

In other words, replace the includes at the top of each PHP file with a require_once() which "bootstraps" a class which defines the logic for autoloading. And when writing automated tests, "inject" alternative autoloading logic for the classes to be "mocked" at the top of each test script.

It will naturally require a good deal of effort to modify existing code to follow this approach, but the effort appears to be worthwhile both to improve testability and to reduce the total number of lines in the codebase.

Comment: Another approach is to use an Inversion of Control framework (like [Dice](http://r.je/dice.html)) to take care of autoloading and make Dependency Injection easier to implement without getting bogged down in [the courier anti-pattern](http://r.je/oop-courier-anti-pattern.html).

Answer (score 2):

According to php.net, if you use a `return` statement, it'll return execution to script that called it. Which means, `require_once` will stop executing, but the overall script will keep running. Also, examples on php.net show that if you return a variable within an included file, then you can do something like `$foo = require_once('myfile.php');` and `$foo` will contain the returned value from the included file. If you don't return anything, then `$foo` is `1` to show that `require_once` was successful. Read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) for more examples.

And I don't see anything on php.net that says anything specifically about how the php interpreter will parse included statements, but your testing shows that it first resolves class definitions before executing code in-line.

UPDATE

I added some tests as well, by modifying `Z.inc` as follows:

```
    $test = new Z();
    echo $test->foo();
    if (defined ('MOCK_Z')) {
        return true;
    }
    class Z {
        function foo() {
            print "This is foo() from the original version of class Z.\n";
        }
    }
```

And then tested on the command line as follows:

```
    %> php A.inc
    => This is foo() from a local version of class Z.
       This is foo() from a local version of class Z.

    %> php B.inc
    => This is foo() from the original version of class Z.
       This is foo() from the original version of class Z.
```

Obviously, name hoisting is happening here, but the question remaining is why there are no complaints about re-declarations?

UPDATE

So, I tried to declare class `Z` twice in `A.inc` and I got the fatal error, but when I tried to declare it twice in `Z.inc`, I didn't get an error. This leads me to believe that the php interpreter will return execution to the file that did the including when a fatal runtime error occurs in an included file. That is why `A.inc` did not use `Z.inc`'s class definition. It was never put into the environment, because it caused a fatal error, returning execution back to `A.inc`.

UPDATE

I tried the `die();` statement in Z.inc, and it actually does stop all execution. So, if one of your included scripts has a `die` statement, then you will kill your testing.

Comment: Thanks for your investigation, and for the "double declaration" experiment (which gives new and useful information). I agree that the lack of redeclaration error is mysterious. But I can't believe that PHP is "silently" returning from processing the include/require when it encounters a fatal error, since *any* fatal error ought to interrupt execution of the script (this is in fact the behavior you observed when you put a die(); statement in Z.inc).

Comment: Yes, it is very strange. Unfortunately, it looks like php source-code investigation would be necessary to go further :(

Comment: +1 for at least taking a careful look and sharing your observations.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so behavior of the return statement in PHP included files is to return control to the parent in execution.  That means the classes definitions are parsed and accessible during the compile phase.  For instance, if you change the above to the following

a.php:

```
<?php
define('MOCK_Z', true);

require_once('z.php');

class Z {
    public function foo() {
        print "This is foo() from a local version of class Z in a.php\n";
    }
}

$a = new Z();
$a->foo();

?>
```

b.php:

```
<?php

    define('MOCK_Z', true);
    require_once('z.php');
    $a = new Z();
    $a->foo();

?>
```

z.php:

```
<?php

if (defined ('MOCK_Z')) {
    echo "MOCK_Z definition found, returning\n";
    return false;
}

echo "MOCK_Z definition not found defining class Z\n";

class X { syntax error here ; }

class Z {
    function foo() {
        print "This is foo() from the original version of class Z.\n";
    }
}

?>
```

then `php a.php` and `php b.php` will both die with syntax errors; which indicates that the return behavior is not evaluated during compile phase!

So this is how you go around it:

z.php:

```
<?php

$z_source = "z-real.inc";

if ( defined(MOCK_Z) ) {
    $z_source = "z-mock.inc";
}

include_once($z_source);

?>
```

z-real.inc:

```
<?php
class Z {
    function foo() {
            print "This is foo() from the z-real.inc.\n";
        }
}

?>
```

z-mock.inc:

```
<?php
class Z {
    function foo() {
            print "This is foo() from the z-mock.inc.\n";
        }
}

?>
```

Now the inclusion is determined at runtime :^) because the decision is not made until `$z_source` value is evaluated by the engine.

Now you get desired behavior, namely:

`php a.php` gives:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Z in /Users/masud/z-real.inc on
>   line 2

and `php b.php` gives:

> This is foo() from the z-real.inc.

Of course you can do this directly in a.php or b.php but doing the double indirection may be useful ...

## NOTE

Having SAID all of this, of course this is a terrible way to build stubs hehe for unit-testing or for any other purpose :-) ... but that's beyond the scope of this question so I shall leave it to your good devices.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your investigation. I agree that the included files are *checked in some way* - and syntax errors in them do indeed cause the inclusion (and script) to fail. But the included files are *not* "parsed" in the same way that PHP files are parsed when executed. If they *were*, then the "duplicate definition scenario" described in Ryan's answer would also cause the inclusion to fail, but it does not.

Comment: On further study, PHP is exhibiting behavior that is COUNTER to what is expressed in the documentation.

Comment: +1 for digging deeper. Would you care to explain how the observed behavior contradicts the documentation?

Comment: As to your remark about building stubs, I'll repeat to you what I wrote to Matthew: I have found that in practice it is far from easy to get more than very modest test coverage without injecting mock objects (aka test doubles) somehow, and since PHP doesn't make "monkey patching" very easy (like, say, Python) then I'm forced to choose between hacking includes, physically replacing files, and upend class hierarchies in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the answer is that class declarations are compile-time, but duplicate class definition errors are run-time *at the point in the code that the class is declared*.  The first time a class definition is in a parsed block, it is immediately made available for use; by returning from an included file early, you aren't preventing class declaration, but you *are* bailing out before the error is thrown.

For example, here are a bunch of class definitions for Z:

```
$ cat A.php
<?php
error_reporting(-1);

$init_classlist = get_declared_classes();
require_once("Z.php");
var_dump(array_diff(get_declared_classes(), $init_classlist));

class Z {
  function test() {
    print "Modified Z from A.php.\n";
  }
}

$z = new Z();
$z->test();

return;

class Z {
  function test() {
    print "Another Z from A.php.\n";
  }
}


$ cat Z.php
<?php
echo "In Z.php!\n";
return;

class Z {
  function test() {
    print "Original Z.\n";
  }
}
```

When `A.php` is called, the following is produced:

```
In Z.php!
array(0) {
}
Modified Z from A.php.
```

This shows that the declared classes don't change upon entering `Z.php` - the Z class is already declared by `A.php` further down the file.  However, `Z.php` never gets a change to complain about the duplicate definition due to the return before the class declaration.  Similarly, `A.php` doesn't get a chance to complain about the second definition in the same file because it also returns before the second definition is reached.

Conversely, removing the first `return;` in `Z.php` instead produces:

```
In Z.php!

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Z in Z.php on line 4
```

By simply not returning early from `Z.php`, we reach the class declaration, which has a chance to produce its run-time error.

In summary: class declaration is compile-time, but duplicate definition errors are run-time at the point the class declaration appears in the code.

(Of course, having not confirmed this with the PHP internals, it might be doing something completely different, but the behavior is consistent with my description above. Tested in PHP 5.5.14.)

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest thing I could find in the manual:

> If there are functions defined in the included file, they can be used in the main file independent if they are before return() or after. If the file is included twice, PHP 5 issues fatal error because functions were already declared, while PHP 4 doesn't complain about functions defined after return().

And this is true regarding functions. If you define the same function in A and Z (after the return) with PHP 5, you'll get a fatal error as you expect.

However, classes seem to fall back to PHP 4 behavior, where it doesn't complain about functions defined after return. To me this seems like a bug, but I don't see where the documentation says what *should* happen with classes.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I agree that the documentation fails to clarify what the behavior ought to be, which is why I'm sure the Gods of PHP would deny that this is a bug.